# Is direct transfer from Dropbox to FTP possible?

Tags: ftp, google-drive-api, cloud, dropbox

Is there a way, to setup directl file transfer from Dropbox/Google Drive/OneDrive... to FTP server. Is it "physically" possible or/and does any API and programming logic even allow that?

Comment: Do you ask for a Dropbox folder synced with a ftp folder: You put a file in a dropbox folder and then start a transfer of this file to a ftp folder?

Comment: Nope, I was thinking direct from dropbox.com to ftp://somewhere.remote

Comment: It's not possible direct from dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

No, Dropbox does not offer an FTP interface or functionality like this. Dropbox offers an HTTP based API:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core

You could use that API to programmatically download content from Dropbox, and then upload that to an FTP server, but that would require a client in the middle to manage the download and upload.